# Make an element non-rectangular in CSS to write text

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I have a heading element which is supposed to have a trapezium like shape. The text inside the heading element has to follow the boundary of the trapezium instead of a rectangular box.

Is it possible to do so in CSS?

Here is a reference image:

[image]

As you can see, the text is rectangular in shape and does not respect the boundary of the black background.

Here is my CSS and HTML so far:

```css
div.container {
  width: 1920px;
  height: 1080px;
  background: linear-gradient(120deg, black 50%, white 50%);
}
h1 {
  font-size: 3.5rem;
  padding: 2rem 1rem;
  color: white;
  text-align:  center;
  width: 940px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <h1>This is any random piece of text.</h1>
</div>
```

I tried adding another `div` before `h1` and apply the `shape-outside` property on it but no matter what value I give it. Nothing change.

Thanks.

Comment: As far as I know it's not possible to make any html element other than rectangular, and you will need for sure a html element parent such as a div or whatever else to constrain the text inside of it and take its width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You’re currently achieving the white shape by setting a background gradient. Instead, use shape-outside to actually create the shape and let the text wrap around it. Like this:

```css
.container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

.shape {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-shape-outside: polygon(100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
  shape-outside: polygon(100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
  float: right;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
}

p {
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="shape"></div>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi eu erat pharetra orci rhoncus dignissim. Nullam imperdiet justo felis, id venenatis velit pretium in. Donec commodo odio nisl, ut facilisis dui vulputate at. Nullam feugiat semper urna non efficitur. 
  </p>
</div>
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

That could be achieved, if the text would wrap around another element that has:

```
.wrap-around {
 float: left;
 shape-outside: polygon("settings");
 clip-path: polygon("settings");
}
```

Where the settings, of course, would be tailored to suit your needs.

[Take a look here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/shape-outside)

Personally I was not able to edit the following snippet to resemble your example, but this would absolutely be one way to do it.

Example From the mozilla mdn:

```css
.main {
  width: 530px;
}

.left,
.right {
  width: 40%;
  height: 12ex;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

.left {
  -webkit-shape-outside: polygon(0 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
  shape-outside: polygon(0 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
  float: left;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
}

.right {
  -webkit-shape-outside: polygon(100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
  shape-outside: polygon(100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
  float: right;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
}

p {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
  <p>
    Sometimes a web page's text content appears to be
    funneling your attention towards a spot on the page
    to drive you to follow a particular link. Sometimes
    you don't notice.
  </p>
</div>
```